# Send MailMessage object to WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have been asked to set up a service using WebApi 2.1 which will be able to take a MailMessage object as a parameter, send that mail message, and log that the message has been sent.

I have patterned my attempt based on the following example from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/bson-support-in-web-api-21

Here are the actions in my controller:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/Email/SendMailMessage")]
        public async Task SendMailMessage(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg)
        {
            await _emailSender.SendMailMessageAsync(msg);
        }
```

Here is the test method which calls the API:

```cs
        public async void TestMailMessage()
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            // snip details of msg population for brevity

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:40353/");

                // Set the Accept header for BSON.
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));

                // POST using the BSON formatter.
                MediaTypeFormatter bsonFormatter = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter();
                var result = await client.PostAsync("api/Email/SendMailMessage", msg, bsonFormatter);

            }
        }
```

Startup.cs

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddMvc().AddBsonSerializerFormatters();
            services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

The problem I have is that the MailMessage object is coming through as null on the server.

Alternately I tried to serialize the object as bytes, but that has failed because the MailMessage class is not serializable.

Comment: `MailMessage` isn't serializable, so serializing it into BSON probably won't work.  Make a DTO containing the properties you want to transmit and send that instead.

Comment: What is the reason for calling `services.AddMvc()` twice ?

Comment: @spidyx, I got rid of the first services.AddMvc().

Comment: @Amy - I tried replacing the MailMessage with a dto which I have declared as serializable.  It still came across as null, so I tried paring it down to an object containing just from, to, subject, and body, but the controller still sees it as a null object.